# unable to connect my mobile to jmeter5.4.1 (mac)for load testing. I am a complete beginner?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, manual-testing, automation-testing

I have done all steps mentioned online to connect mobile to jmeter from wifi setting, certificate installation and also mentioned my mac ip in mobile local host.After all this I can't record or connect by mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing these "all steps" we cannot provide comprehensive answer, the most common problem is forgetting [enabling full trust for the JMeter's certificate](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204477)

[image]

Once you tick enable this assuming that you network configuration is correct, to wit:

1. Cellular/bluetooth/usb connectivity is disabled on iOS device
2. JMeter and the iOS device are on the same network/subnet
3. JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) is up and running (you need to click "Start" button)
4. No [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)) is blocking inbound connections to the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder default port `8888`

you should be able to record.

Alternative option is using [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/ios/) for iOS device traffic capture, once you export the captured requests as [HAR file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAR_(file_format)) you should be able to convert it into JMeter Test Script using [BlazeMeter Converter](https://converter.blazemeter.com/) online service

Comment: i am using android mobile app and jmeter5.4.1 is intalled in mac.

Comment: I'm not telepathic enough to guess what "mobile" do you mean, for Android check out [Recording Using Android Devices](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Recording-Using-Android-Devices-Recording-Using-Android-Devices) and [Changes to Trusted Certificate Authorities in Android Nougat](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/changes-to-trusted-certificate.html) articles

Comment: android version: 8.1.0 Oreo